# Page template for a site from network

Tags: templates, wp-admin, page-template

Is there a way to dispay in the Wordpress admin distinct templates based on which blog you are ?

Let's say that for the blog `travel` I have the page template `page-travel.php`. How can I hide it on all the blogs and dispay the template only on the travel blog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the filter `theme_page_templates` present since `3.9.0` like so:

```
function my_theme_page_templates( $page_templates, $this, $post ) {
    $travel_blog_id = 2;
    $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

    if($blog_id != $travel_blog_id) {
        if(isset($page_templates['page-travel.php'])) {
            unset($page_templates['page-travel.php']);
        }
    }

    return $page_templates;
}
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'my_theme_page_templates', 20, 3 );
```